# Data loss while un-tar

Tags: linux, ftp, solaris, tar

I have created a tar file of a directory on solaris containing 68 files  using

```
tar -cvf file.tar file_name
```

but this was missing out 3 files whose name was too long .So, I used -E option to tar all the files irrespective of their name.This worked fine and all the files were included in the tar

```
tar -cvef file.tar file_name
```

Now when I ftp this tar to linux server and untar it using

```
tar -xvf file.tar
```

Some files whose name is long get missed out and I get 65 files when I untar it.Can anyone help to untar and get all the files on linux box.I could not find an option similar to -E in linux.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Install [star](http://linux.die.net/man/1/star) and use this command:

```
star -xp artype=suntar f=file.tar
```